# What is wrong with this AS3 code to communicate with a PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash, url

I am trying to create a user log-in system in Flash but I need to communicate to MySQL through PHP in order to do so. I looked around at a few tutorials, but I have been getting errors.

Here is the interface I have made in flash, which I am trying to communicate with controlpanel.php

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB3C7.png

Here is the code

AS file

```
package actions
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class main extends MovieClip
    {
        public function main():void
        {
            submit_button.buttonMode = true;
            submit_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkLogin)

            username.text = "";
            password.text = "";
        }

        public function checkLogin(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if(username.text==""||password.text=="")
            {
                if (username.text == "")
                {
                    username.text = "Enter your username";      
                }

                if (password.text == "")
                {
                    password.text="Enter your password";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                processLogin();
            }
        }

        public function processLogin():void
        {
            var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            var phpFileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://mathlympics.cu.cc/php/controlpanel.php");
            phpFileRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
            phpFileRequest.data = phpVars;

            var phpLoader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
            phpLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

            phpVars.systemCall = "checkLogin";
            phpVars.username = username.text;
            phpVars.password = password.text;

            phpLoader.load(phpFileRequest);
            phpLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, showResult);
        }

        public function showResult(event:Event):void
        {
            result_text.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            result_text.text = ""+ event.target.data.systemResult;
        }
    }
}
```

PHP file - connect.php

```
<?php
$db_username = "censored";
$db_name = "censored";
$db_password = "censored";
$db_host = "mysql2.000webhost.com";
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

PHP file - controlpanel.php

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("connect.php");
$username       = "admin";
$password       = "password";
$sql            = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$query          = mysql_query($sql);
$login_counter  = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($login_counter > 0)
{
    $data       = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $userbio    = $data["user_bio"];
    echo "systemResult=" . $userbio;
}
else
{
    echo "systemResult=Invalid";    
}
?>
```

I do not get any error but when I press the submit button, is says undefined in the result text box, even when I type the right username and password.

```
<!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

To those of you interested: Here is my website [enter link description here](http://mathlympics.cu.cc/loginsystem.swf)

Comment: Try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the controlpanel.php file and see if you get any error messages.

On a side note, you might want to read up on SQL Injection.  (For example, if a user submitted `' OR 1=1--` as a username)

Comment: try hitting that php page from your browser and fill in some values where your `$_POST` data would be

Comment: @Ronnie I am running it on the following website http://mathlympics.cu.cc/. I tried to access the php file directly and then it just echoes that the login details dont match out records.

Comment: try assigning the values to the URLVariables and then adding it to the request

Comment: use some records that are legit then..put this into your PHP file and test http://pastie.org/5513290

Comment: I'm using Charles web debugging proxy and when I put a username/pass into that login page you made, I get an error: `mysql_num_rows supplied argument is not a valid mysql resource...etc` Also, your web host keeps injecting that javascript in all your pages.

Comment: @Ronnie Thanks for help! But where should I proceed from here. At the moment I have only one user 'admin' with password 'password' in my database. Should I add more? And what should I do about JavaScript? Thanks for helping! sorry i am a newb

Comment: I just said you are getting an error in your php saying mysql_num_rows: supplied argument invalid..Post the PHP that you have on your server as of now..not all that commented out stuff

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean by the Javascript. I am stuck with it due to the host. Thanks for calrifying.

Comment: @Ronnie updated the controlpanel.php code. Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: try replacing `$query = mysql_query($sql);` with `$query = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I even did what Gone3d said, assigning the variables to the URLVariables, but event that did not work

Comment: hey do you have skype? It wont let you join chat since you dont have enough rep

Comment: @Ronnie Aha! After adding 'or die' function, nothing is displayed even after entering the wrong password and username. I think there must be problem with my database then?

Comment: `Table 'a5939459_data.user' doesn't exist` That is saying the table you are trying to select does not exist. Are you sure you have a table named `user`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem ended up being you had `SELECT * FROM user...` when it should have been `SELECT * FROM users...` =)

Comment: The sort of mistake that can cost you hours trying to find the solution.